# Retrieving mode (Basic|Advanced) of ADF query component

Tags: oracle-adf

I want to capture query component mode(Basic | Advanced) in processQuery event listener method for QueryEvent as below:

```
public void processQuery(QueryEvent queryEvent)
{
// Add event code here...
QueryDescriptor qdesc = queryEvent.getDescriptor();
String searchName = qdesc.getName();
String queryMode =?
```

I tried to get this value from getUIHints() map using UIHINT_MODE key. but getUIHints() returns empty map.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
ViewCriteria vc = null;
try
{
  Method m =
    pQueryDescriptor.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getViewCriteria",
                                                  null);
  m.setAccessible(true);
  vc = (ViewCriteria) m.invoke(pQueryDescriptor, null);
}
catch (Exception ite)
{
  _logger.logp(Level.SEVERE, CLAZZ_NAME, methodName,
               "Exception getting ViewCriteria from QueryDescriptor.",
               ite);
} 
 String searchType =
      (String) vc .getProperty(ViewCriteriaHints.CRITERIA_MODE);
```

The idea is to get the ViewCriteria from the QueryDescriptor and to get the mode from the VC. This is becasue the mode is set on the criteria object itself, the VC knows how to display and what to display in each mode, and so it makes the MODE an inherent property of the VC and not just a UI thing....

Answer (score 1):

```
QueryDescriptor qdesc = queryEvent.getDescriptor();
QueryDescriptor.QueryMode mode = (QueryDescriptor.QueryMode) qdesc.getUIHints().get(qdesc.UIHINT_MODE);
```

if("BASIC".equals(mode.toString())){

```
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some verbal expalantion to your code?